# Reddened in the face / red skin in the face

Tags: coloration-discoloration, face, uv-rays, hyperpigmentation, flush-face-body

i have red skin in my face since a couple months. I thought it is coming from drinking because I spent like 3 weeks drinking every second day with a friend who visited me and afterwards I got problems with my skin, as well this reddening.

I have it for months now and the dermatologist told me to use something to heal tissue and to apply basically sun lotion. Well I did that for 10 days straight i applied a sun cream and the healing lotion, and I still look like this.

any wild ideas what else it could be?

yes yes, seek help from a professional yeah right, I have another appointment soon. But each doctor tends to say something else, and I wanted to see here if someone has advice /  a wild guess.

So: I lately got a bit of dermatitis / neurodermitis again, a disease I used to have a lot more when I was a baby. Now I barely ever get it.

it looks like sun burn to me, but I am almost never in the sun (I am a programmer, food delivers at noon to my place typically). If someone would tell me sun burn -> i would tell him that it might be the lack of sun, but not sun burn for sure.

i have a new notebook since a couple months. Can it be the light emitted by the screen? probably not because I read flatscreens do not emit UV.

Food?

Comment: Sorry but s
ite rules prohibit us from offering personal medical advice.

Comment: Blood pressure maybe elevated alcohol can bring that about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities here, but my first thought upon seeing the pictures and reading that it occurred after you increased your alcohol consumption was rosacea. It can be triggered by alcohol consumption. Certain foods can trigger it as well. You'll want to google "rosacea" and "rosacea triggers" because there's much more info out there than I can easily summarize here.

Another big possibility is allergies/atopic dermatitis/eczema. Did you change any product usage like soaps, detergents, shampoo, or conditioner which come into contact with the skin? Have you started eating any new foods that you now eat frequently? Any other recent environmental changes?

Follow up with your dermatologist. It may take several visits to narrow down and pinpoint some diagnoses that have nonspecific symptoms, and sometimes it even comes down to trial and error with several treatment options. If you don't get anywhere after that, perhaps seek another opinion.

Comment: she prescribed me with hyalix, basically hydrating the skin, soolantra crema 1% ivermectina, which is supposed to work well against rosacea.  As well an increase in use of the sun lotion (umbrella plus). And continue to take the healing lotion (avena cicalfate)